# Why isn't my consumable item working?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I followed a tutorial online. I have all this code coming before my onCreate

```
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        btnPurchase.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStats.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purchasepressed);
                    test.setText("IT WORKS!!!");

                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
            }
        };
public void consumeItem() throws IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);

}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    try {
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
                resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) throws IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException {


        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU), mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};


public void buyClick(View view) throws IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException {


 mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase) throws IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {

            btnPurchase.setEnabled(false);
            btnPurchase.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purchasepressed);
            test.setText("IT WORKS!!!");


        }

    }
};
```

I was under the impression that after purchase.getSKU().equals(ITEM_SKU)
you put whatever code should be executed if the purchase was successful.

As you can see here, if the purchase is successful, my purchase button should be disabled and change its background image. Also I added a test text label to see if the error was somewhere else in my code.

When I run the code on my phone, I get the purchase dialog and the success, but the button and text don't change.

Please help.